# Inline style within HTML textarea gets ignored

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I recently started my first project with JHipster and created two entities.
One of the entitys resembles a blog. That blog has an content attribute which works with a textarea. at my `blogs.html`file I enabled the use of html-tags in my textarea like so:

```
<div ng-bind-html="topic.content"></div>
```

That works without a problem. I am able to define html-tags in my textarea and they get interpreted as such.

But the problem starts with styling my newly formed attributes.
a simple div with inline styles:

```
<div style="font-size:100px"> Test</div>
```

gets interpreted as html but the style gets skipped.
I also tryed to use ng-style instead:

```
 <div ng-style="font-size:100px"> Test</div>`
```

but that didnt work either. In the case that my styles might get overwritten I also tryed to set the `!important` flag without success.

It is a little difficult for me to provide actual code, as jhipster generated my entitys completly autonomic. I cant identify if some script would override my styles or forbade the use of style tags as whole. Never the less I made some pictures which might help to grasp the problem:

this is my textarea in which the user does his input
[image: this is my textarea in which the user does his input]

this is how the result looks, notice the "test" text should be colored:

[image: this is how the result looks, notice the "test" text should be coloured]

Last but not least I try to provide how my browser resolves the attribute:

[image: how my browser resolves the attribute]

I appreciate your help!

Comment: did u tried "!important"  <div style="font-size:100px !important"> Test</div> could possible that yous style getting override somewhere. If not then can you provide me sample?

Comment: @user3249448 I already tryed that one. I forgot to mention it in my question. Thanks

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a Fiddle? Also can you post an image of the Dev Tools while inspecting that div? It could really help, thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried applying style by means of "ng-style" directive and object notation? Eg.  ng-style="{ 'font-size' : '100px' }"

Comment: @Vi Unfortunately that didnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the sanitizer is stripping out the style tag...

Inject the $sce service in your controller an map the trustAsHtml function to the view:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

then you can do this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(topic.content)"></div>
```

That should solve your problem, but be aware that your topic.content comes from a verified source (not from the user input) or you could an injection attack...